# Overlaying transparent png on picamera preview is ugly

Tags: python

I have a raspberry pi with camera module and I'm trying to overlay a transparent PNG over the camera preview.

I used the sample code from http://picamera.readthedocs.org/ (changing `tostring()` to `tobytes()` as it's deprecated):

```
import picamera
from PIL import Image
from time import sleep

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution = (1280, 720)
    camera.vflip = True
    camera.start_preview()

    # Load the arbitrarily sized image
    img = Image.open('3.png')
    # Create an image padded to the required size with
    # mode 'RGB'
    pad = Image.new('RGB', (
        ((img.size[0] + 31) // 32) * 32,
        ((img.size[1] + 15) // 16) * 16,
        ))
    # Paste the original image into the padded one
    pad.paste(img, (0, 0))

    # Add the overlay with the padded image as the source,
    # but the original image's dimensions
    o = camera.add_overlay(pad.tobytes(), size=img.size)
    # By default, the overlay is in layer 0, beneath the
    # preview (which defaults to layer 2). Here we make
    # the new overlay semi-transparent, then move it above
    # the preview
    o.alpha = 128
    o.layer = 3

    # Wait indefinitely until the user terminates the script
    while True:
        sleep(1)
```

.. but the overlay is unreadable, there is a square over the text.

This is what the image looks like by itself:
[image]

and this is what it looks like when overlayed on the camera preview:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Deon,

You need to make the image a `RGBA`and pass the image twice in paste:

```
pad = Image.new('RGBA',
        ((img.size[0] + 31) // 32) * 32,
        ((img.size[1] + 15) // 16) * 16,
        ))

pad.paste(img, (0, 0), img)
```

The third argument is the transparency mask. It will read the alpha from your image and apply it.